# How to get next and previous records from a model with a parent child relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, model

I have a parent child relationship in my model where a `Section` can have many subsections. so in my model I have joined the table onto itself and using a `parent` column I can determine which section is a parent / child.

My question is how would I retrieve the next and previous records for the subsections?

My `Section` model:

```
    class Section extends Model
    {
        use BelongsToSortedManyTrait, SortableTrait;


        public $fillable = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'parent',
            'position'
        ];


        public function subsections() {
            return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent')->sorted();
        }

       public function next(){
        // get next record
        return self::where('id', '>', $this->id)->orderBy('id','asc')->first();

       }

       public  function previous(){
        // get previous record
        return self::where('id', '<', $this->id)->orderBy('id','desc')->first();

    }

    }
```

Notice the previous and next methods, at the moment they will work for all sections but won't take into account the parent / child relationship.

Any way I can achieve this?

Comment: change `self::` to `$this->` may fix[not tested]

Comment: Calling `next()` on a subsection should get the next subsection, right? Not the next parent section.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir It would get the next section record, which could be the parent section as its using the same table.

Comment: when you are in child ( subsection ) you wanna access the next / previous sibling of the parent, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has not been tested but try:

```
self::where('parent', $this->parent)
    ->where('id', '<', $this->id)
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->first();
```

Adding the parent to the query will restrict the next value to those with the same parent ID. You can then use like this:

```
$subsection = Section::find(2);
$next = $subsection->next();
$prev = $subsection->previous();
```

Furthermore, it may be better to make next and previous parent query optional:

```
public function next($parent = false) {
    $query = self::query();

    if ($parent) {
        $query = $query->where('parent', $this->parent);
    }

    $query = $query->where('id', '<', $this->id)
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->first();
}
```

This will allow you to check the next and previous section as well as subsections.

All the best.

**Update** (API solution - this has not been tested)

```
$section = Section::find($id); // Whatever the section id is;

$subsection = Section::where('parent', $section->id)->first();

return [
    'section'         => $section,
    'next_section'    => $section->next()->id,
    'prev_section'    => $section->prev()->id,
    'subsection'      => $subsection,
    'next_subsection' => $subsection->next(true)->id,
    'prev_subsection' => $subsection->prev(true)->id,
];
```

On the next section call, you can then pass the subsection id and run next/prev before returning the api:

`$subsection = Section::find(1)->next()`;

Comment: So then if I have a query builder in my API that returns a JSON response of the sections with the subsections how can I use the above function to include the next and previous records?

`public function first()
    {
        return $this->model->with('sections.subsections')->first();
    }`

Comment: You could map the returned collection to add the next and previous using the new functions. Or you could create a new array which returns what you need. However, the prev and next functions are based on having a subsection to begin with. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @user3574492 are you trying to retrieve all subsections in your api, or just one and then point to the next and previous (if they exist)?

Comment: All sections along with subsections. I'd prefer the final JSON to include the next and previous records for both sections and subsections if they exist. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I understand your answer would work perfectly if you already have a subsection record to begin with, but as I am using a query builder for a JSON API it works a little differently as I can't use eager loading etc...

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167427/discussion-between-user3574492-and-thisiskelvin).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function next(){
    $id = $this->parent ?: $this->id;
    return self::where('id', '>', $id)->orderBy('id','asc')->first();
}

public  function previous(){
    $id = $this->parent ?: $this->id;
    return self::where('id', '<', $id)->orderBy('id','desc')->first();
}
```